# Azure DevOps release pipelines : can't find the new "Export YAML" menu item

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

Starting today the "View YAML" button in Azure DevOps both for build pipelines and for release pipeline is directing to the "Runs page" where an "Export YAML" menu item should be available. I found it for build pipelines but I can't see this menu item for release pipelines. It would make it so much easier for users to simply navigate the browser to the new location instead of providing only a text description to the new location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work for releases and it won't be. This is a bug which I already reported on Develop Community [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1278001/view-yaml-doesnt-work-for-releases.html). Please upvote if so we show that we want to at least `view YAML` button back on releases.

Please check Matt'c comment below [the article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/replacing-view-yaml/):

> No plans to do so. Classic RM pipelines are different enough in their execution that I can’t make the same strong guarantees about correctness as I can with classic Build. Also, a number of concepts were re-thought between RM and unified YAML pipelines. In some cases, there isn’t a direct translation for an RM feature. A human is required to think about what the pipeline is designed to accomplish and re-implement it using new constructs.